Почему если записать c_str() (из возвращаемой string ) в массив const char * arr[1] то в массиве не оказывается строки?
Почему если записать c_str() (из возвращаемой string ) в элемент массива const char * arr[1] то в элементе массива не окажется строки?
Но если раскомментировать строку uncomment me то все будет работать как ожидается
string func(){ return string{"hello!"};}

int main() {

    const char * arr[1];
   // cout<<"func().c_str(): "<<func().c_str()<<endl; //uncomment me 
    arr[0] = func().c_str();
    
    cout<<"arr[0]: "<<arr[0]<<endl; //expected hello!

}

Output:
arr[0]:

можно пользоваться не указателем на строку, а ссылкой на временный объект типа string. string && tmp=func(); тогда время жизни объекта tmp продлится.

Время жизни возвращаемой строки к моменту вывода закончилось, и она уничтожена...
Попробуйте так:
string tmp = func();
arr[0] = tmp.c_str();

cout<<"arr[0]: "<<arr[0]<<endl; //expected hello!


да, так будет работать, но не хотелось бы создавать лишних переменных (конечно если иначе нельзя то придется).
Причем будет работать даже так:
string tmp = func();
arr[0] = func().c_str();

Если не создавать "лишних" переменных, то никто не будет владеть памятью, на которую указывает arr[0]. А если нет памяти, нет и значения.

"не хотелось бы создавать лишних переменных" переменная тут не лишняя. Вы пытаетесь сохранить указатель на данные в куче (а не на стеке). Поэтому выхода тут (как минимум) 3: 1. либо вручную через new создавать буфер, копировать туда данные из выбранного источника, и самому удалять этот буфер, когда будет не нужен, через delete; 2. Воспользоваться готовым классом, в котором этот механизм уже реализован (от, что предложил @Harry); 3. Либо изменить логику программы (например: https://godbolt.org/z/rGha8s8q8)

@vasliliy Чтобы не создавать лишних переменных и не писать лишних выражений стоило бы хранить строку в массиве, задавая значение сразу при инициализации. ::std::array arr{func()};

Вот так, как вы написали - string tmp = func(); arr[0] = func().c_str(); - работать не будет... Может сработать, как, например, при проезде через закрытый переезд поезд не обязательно снесет. Но в общем случае работать не будет.
